# ParentClass is an inaccessible base of ChildClass

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am writing the following code in c++ but i am getting an inaccessible type error, but when I inherit the child classes publicly with parent all goes well. I have searched about this problem but didn't get anything.
Kindly help me doing this right, this is my assignment and I have to inherit the classes privately.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class publication
{
    private:
    string name;
    int id;
    public:
    virtual void getdata()
    {
        cout<<"Enter Name: ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter ID: ";
        cin>>id;        
    }
    virtual void putdata ()
    {
        cout<<name;
        cout<<id;       
    }

};
class book: private publication
{
    private:
    int pages;
    public:
    void getdata()
    {
        publication::getdata();
        cout<<"Enter Pages: ";
        cin>>pages; 
    }
    void putdata ()
    {
        publication::putdata();
        cout<<pages;
    }
};
class tape: private publication
{
    private:
    float ptime;
    public:
    void getdata()
    {
        publication::getdata();
        cin>>ptime;
    }
     void putdata ()
    {
        publication::putdata();
        cout<<time;
    }
};
int main()
{
    publication *ptr[2];

            ptr[0] = new book;
            ptr[0]->getdata();
            ptr[0]->putdata();

            ptr[1] = new tape;
            ptr[1]->getdata();
            ptr[1]->putdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using private inheritance. This means you inherit the fields and methods of the superclass, but you can only access them from within the class itself or from its friend classes and functions. Other functions will not even know the inheritance exists, and may not use the subclass like an instance of a base class.

You are using your subclass in main. You create new objects of the subclass types, but then (implicitly) cast them to a pointer to the superclass. Since main is not a friend function of the subclass, it isn't allowed to use the subclass as if it were a base class. Therefor the compiler gives you an error.

It would seem right to use public inheritance in this case. Since all functions may know that "book" and "tape" are subclasses of "publication".

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right: pointers to objects of type `book` and type `tape` cannot be converted into pointers to objects of type `publication` because `publication` is a private base. If you are required to use private bases, then you need to do something different in the rest of your code, but there's no hint in the question of what that code is supposed to do, so it's really not possible to say anything more here.

Answer (score 0):

When you have inheritance in a Childclass that means that all the functions and data of the Parentclass also belong to child. So you should invoke the getdata function with this->getdata not publication::getdata. Inheritance always boggles me so I am not 100% sure. Yet I believe it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it.
 It can be done by making main function friend of *book* class and *tape* class. We don't have to inherit the classes publicly now.